# Regex capture all matches between each set of delimiters

Tags: regex

I need to find all matches in a string that exist between a set of delimiters.

For example, if I have the string `The #quick# brown fox #jumped# over the lazy #dog#.`, I need to get the matches `quick`, `jumped` and `dog`.

I should only get matches that:
 - do not contain the delimiter/  (e.g. `quick` vs `#quick#`).
 - are between sets of delimiters.  That is to say delimiters 1 and 2 are a set, as are delimiters 3 and 4.  I should end up with `quick`, but not `brown fox`.

Here's the regex I have thus far:  `(?<=\#)(.*?)(?=\#)`.  It meets my first criteria, but not my second.

Here is is on on regex101.com:
https://regex101.com/r/bD5mo0/1/

So my question is, how do I get regex to ignore matches *between* sets?  That is to say do match between the first and second delimiter, but not between the second and third.

I know changing the second delimiter to be different than the first will solve this, but the strings I'm regex'ing are coming out of the database, so I'd rather not alter them.

Comment: `(?<=#)[^#\s]*(?=#)` may work. What is your regex platform?

Comment: Otherwise use `#([^#]*)#` and work with capture group #1

Comment: @anubhava ... it's Javascript.

Comment: @anubhava ... looks like it works.  Thanks.  Add it to an answer, and I'll mark it accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to capture string between a pair of `#`s only then it is better to use this regex with a capture group:

```
/#([^#]*)#/
```

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bD5mo0/2)

You need to avoid using zero width look arounds for this regex as we need to match `#`s as well while moving ahead in inout.